# Unable to infer using Autoencoders neural network model (model.h5)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

As per the link https://medium.com/@curiousily/credit-card-fraud-detection-using-autoencoders-in-keras-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vii-20e0c85301bd

we are trying to run fraud detection using Autoencoders. while undergoing prediction with the sample input we are using **predictions = autoencoder.predict(X_test)**

The input(**X_test**) is complete record stack, How do i pass single customer record as input by which it infer the required. pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

using the below approach was able to send single record to predict function
x=[402,-0.160626023844866,-0.0644592715749079,2.53107242920104]
b=np.reshape(x,(1,4))

predictions = autoencoder.predict(b,verbose=0)